# create a struct with arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

Hello developers I'm stuck trying to create a struct for improving my code

I have this 3 arrays

```
var storeFuelGradesTypes: [String] = [""]
var storeFuelGradesPrice: [Double] = [0.0]
var storeFuelGradesID: [String] = [""]
```

which the data is fill when the MapVc loads 10 times (for getting the API response for markers)

```
WalletService.shared.locateAndCheckinToNearestStore(toExplicitLocation: CLLocation(latitude: station.lat, longitude: station.long)) { storee, error in
  WalletService.shared.getSiteDetails { siteDetails, error in
     guard let fuelGrades = siteDetails?.fuelGrades else { return }
                                
     //this is how I fill the arrays getting the response from API and append the content from siteDetails and station response 
          let fuelType = fuelGrades.compactMap { $0.fuelType } // this is type [String]
          self?.storeFuelGradesTypes.append(contentsOf: fuelType)
          let priceGrades = fuelGrades.compactMap { $0.price } // this is type [Double]
          self?.storeFuelGradesPrice.append(contentsOf: priceGrades)
          let uriID = station.id. //this is type String
          self?.storeFuelGradesID.append(uriID)
```

after the user moves from the screen selecting the marker

I need to pass the information to the next screen
this is my first issue, since I have the

```
selectedStation?.id
```

**this is the ID and the station information(not the same as the API calls) of user's choice**

I cannot find a way to search on my array:

```
storeFuelGradesID
```

the same ID, lets say the **selectedStation?.id** equals to **- id : "4111"**

and what I have store on my arrays is:

```
(lldb) po storeFuelGradesPrice
▿ 10 elements
  - 0 : 1.339
  - 1 : 1.339
  - 2 : 1.339
  - 3 : 1.339
  - 4 : 1.339
  - 5 : 1.339
  - 6 : 1.339
  - 7 : 1.339
  - 8 : 1.339
  - 9 : 1.339

(lldb) po storeFuelGradesTypes
▿ 10 elements
  - 0 : "REGULAR"
  - 1 : "REGULAR"
  - 2 : "REGULAR"
  - 3 : "REGULAR"
  - 4 : "REGULAR"
  - 5 : "REGULAR"
  - 6 : "REGULAR"
  - 7 : "REGULAR"
  - 8 : "REGULAR"
  - 9 : "REGULAR"

(lldb) po storeFuelGradesID
▿ 10 elements
  - 0 : "4111"
  - 1 : “4222"
  - 2 : “4333"
  - 3 : “5333"
  - 4 : “7888"
  - 5 : “4666"
  - 6 : “2111"
  - 7 : “2222"
  - 8 : “3888"
  - 9 : “9111"

(lldb)
```

I want to create an array that store the 3 types of the information
storeFuelGradesID + storeFuelGradesTypes + storeFuelGradesPrice

and them with the ID that I already have, look with a for statement the ID on the new array (which contains all the information)

Comment: You have a struct to start with in your fuelGrades array, why do you split that up in different arrays to start with? I wrote a similar comment to your earlier question because it feels you are making this unnecessary complicated.

Comment: Don't do that. It's bad practice and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach, using a simple model and some array
functions to get the selected id, and desired info (prices) for example:

```
// the model
struct StoreFuelGrades: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var type: String
    var price: Double
}


 // for testing, an array of info from the API
 let fuelStore = [StoreFuelGrades(id: "1", type: "type-1", price: 1.0),
                  StoreFuelGrades(id: "2", type: "type-2", price: 2.0),
                  StoreFuelGrades(id: "3", type: "type-3", price: 3.0)]
 
 let selectedId = "2"
 // get the selectedId from the fuelStore
 if let selectedFuel = fuelStore.first(where: {$0.id == selectedId}) {
     print("---> selectedFuel: \(selectedFuel)")
 }
 
 // get all prices
 let prices = fuelStore.map{$0.price}
 print("---> prices: \(prices)")
```

Answer (score 0):

silly me I got the answer

I create this structure

```
struct storeFuelGradesInformation {
        var fuelGradesID: String
        var fuelGradesType: [String]
        var fuelGradesPrice: [Double]
        
    }

    var fuelGradesTotalInformationStore: [storeFuelGradesInformation] = []
```

after that fill it with the API response:

```
var captureFuelGrades: storeFuelGradesInformation = storeFuelGradesInformation(fuelGradesID: uriID, fuelGradesType: fuelType, fuelGradesPrice: priceGrades)
```

and append to the fuelGradesTotalInformationStore.append

```
self?.fuelGradesTotalInformationStore.append(captureFuelGrades)
```

after the user select the Marker preference:

```
let idToGet = selectedStation?.id
                
                for arrayToFind in fuelGradesTotalInformationStore {
                    if arrayToFind.fuelGradesID == idToGet{
                        print(arrayToFind)//here I can pass the information safely 
                        return
                    }
                }
```

thanks if anyone has a better idea I'm open to improve

Comment: note I forgot to tell that I'm removing all the information before appending so will not duplicate

Comment: Do you really need arrays for `fuelGradesType` and `fuelGradesPrice`?
Have you tried using something like this: `struct StoreFuelGrades: Identifiable {
 var id: String
 var type: String
 var price: Double
}`

then use an array `[StoreFuelGrades]` when you read the data from the API,
 and use `.filter{...}` to get the `arrays` such as prices. Note the use of the uppercase convention for `struct` types.